# How to upload a pristine Python package to PyPI?

Tags: python, packaging, pypi

What's the magic "`python setup.py some_incantation_here`" command to upload a package to PyPI, in a form that can be downloaded to get the original package in its original form?

I have a package with some source and a few image files (as package_data).  If I do "`setup.py sdist register upload`", the .tar.gz has the image files excluded.  If I do "`setup.py bdist_egg register upload`", the egg contains the images but excludes the setup.py file.  I want to be able to get a file uploaded that is just the entirety of my project -- aka "`setup.py the_whole_freaking_thing register upload`".

Perhaps the best way to do this is to manually tar.gz my project directory and upload it using the PyPI web interface?

Caveat: I'm trying to avoid having to store a simple project I just created in my SVN repo as well as on PyPI -- it seems like a waste of work to keep track of its history and files in two places.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you perform an "sdist" command, then what controls the list of included files is your "MANIFEST.in" file sitting next to "setup.py", not whatever you have listed in "package_data".  This has something to do with the schizophrenic nature of the Python packaging solutions today; "sdist" is powered by the [distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html#distutils-index) in the standard library, while "bdist_egg" is controlled by the [setuptools](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools) module.

To solve the problem, try creating a MANIFEST.in next to your setup.py file, and give it contents like this:

```
include *.jpg
```

Of course, I'm imaging that your "image files" are actual pictures rather than disk images or ISO images or something; you might have to adjust the above line if I've guessed wrong!  But check out the [Specifying which files to distribute](http://docs.python.org/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute) section of the distutils docs, and see whether you can't get those files appearing in your .tar.gz source distribution!  Good luck.

Comment: Perfect!  "include nosenotify/*.png" was the format that I needed, as my files were in a subdirectory -- this format ensured that the .tar.gz nosenotify/ directory contained its .png files.

Comment: PS Brandon, ironically after reading your answer I went to your blog and saw the post from one day before my question, saying you were so fed up with setup.py that you were making pyron. :)