# Why are files missing when I upload an egg to pypi?

Tags: plone, setuptools, distutils, setup.py, pypi

Following the instructions on http://plone.org/documentation/kb/how-to-upload-your-package-to-plone.org/distuttils-commands-and-.pypirc, I uploaded an egg to pypi (adi.workingcopyflag).The created egg is missing some files (configuration.zcml and profiles).

Why are these files missing/how can I fix this?

EDIT: Brandon Rhodes answer [How to upload a pristine Python package to PyPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778980/how-to-upload-a-pristine-python-package-to-pypi) helped.

Adding a MANIFEST.in is the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload a pristine Python package to PyPI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778980/how-to-upload-a-pristine-python-package-to-pypi)

Comment: This no longer seems to be a question.

Comment: That's why I clicked on 'close', seems it takes some time, someone needs to approve the closing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use zest.releaser to automatize the release process - less human mistakes:

http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/08/14/high-quality-automated-package-releases-for-python-with-zest-releaser/

For example, it would have warned you about missing MANIFEST.in.

(disclaimer: my blog post)

Comment: Thanks Mikko, I will have a closer look at this. And at jarn.mkrelease, too ;)

Comment: Well that took a while *cough*, but just wanted to drop, that testing the pre- and postrelease-scripts of zest.releaser gives a very nice impression and saves me of remembering all the nifty details you took the effort to explain in your article, Kiitos! And big thanks to all contributors of this great tool.

Comment: @Mikko, Ida How to include uncommitted files in temp directory when zest releaser clone it? I have few binaries which I need to include in package but they are not committed, they are in my local.

Comment: My gut feeling is that you need to create MANIFEST.in file by hand and make sure those are picked up there. However this answer is 7 years old and there  might be better tools than zest.releaser nowadays.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Umm.. Well, MANIFEST.in is later step. 
Initially, zest.releaser clone your git directory into temp directory and then it perform further process of release from there.
Problem occurs over here, since binaries are available at local but not committed and that is why zest releaser doesn't bring these binaries in temp directory at the time of clone :/
I don't see anything regarding this in documentation :/